# Easier way to convert JSON to CSV?

Tags: angularjs, json, csv

I have a pretty wonky JSON string that looks like this:

```
[[{
    "Table":{
        "Properties":{
            "name":"ABOUT",
            "uniqueConstraints":"{}"
        },
        "Attributes": [{
            "name":"NAME",
            "unique":"true",
            "nullable":"false",
            "insertable":"false",
            "updatable":"false"
        },{
            "name":"VERSION",
            "unique":"true",
            "nullable":"false",
            "insertable":"false",
            "updatable":"false"   // I will need to go back through and add empty element for 'section'
        },{
            "name":"BUILD",           
            "insertable":"true",        
            "section": 1                
        }],
        "FileName": "About.java"
}]]
```

And I'm trying to get a CSV like this:

```
Entity | Property | Unique | Nullable | Insertable | Updatable | Section
=======+==========+========+==========+============+===========+=========
About  | Version  | True   | False    | False      | False     | 
About  | Build    | False  | False    | True       | False     | 1
```

I have a ton of code that I'm currently using to parse this out, and I'm just wondering if anyone knows of an easier way I can accomplish this, with direct association with:

1. Create a header array, we'll call it `header`
2. Create a csv array, we'll call that `csv`
3. Loop through each File and each table in file
4. Loop through Attributes in each table
5. Create a new array inside `csv` called `row`
6. Push the table name & `Table.Attr[i].name` to `row`
7. Parse through each key/value in the Attr (except the name Attr)
8. If the key is something that isn't in `header`, push it
9. Use `header.indexOf(key)` to decide where values should be placed in `csv[row]`
10. After everything's done, go back through and add extra, empty elements to every row.
11. For each row, `Join(",") + "\n"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, non-trivial problem. I haven't tried it, but there is an article by a chap who has done something along these lines. Might be worth a few minutes of your time to see if it comes close to what you need https://sunlightfoundation.com/blog/2014/03/11/making-json-as-simple-as-a-spreadsheet/

He talks about dealing with arrays of data and padding out columns...

Comment: Yeah, that was a good article and tool. I just decided to forge ahead. Thanks!